# Where does Heroku store its databases?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

In light of the recent AWS outage (and thus Heroku outage), I started thinking a little bit more about the Heroku stack. I was wondering - where does Heroku store my DB exactly? I have the free postgres shared DB that they give with each app ... does that sit on some EC2 cloud somewhere? It is not RDS right, since those are all MySQL DBs...?

Thanks,
Ringo

Comment: ask him directly. Heroku staff is very efficient and valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EC2, with the write ahead logs continuously shipped to S3 via [WAL-E](https://github.com/heroku/wal-e).

Answer (score 0):

They are on EC2 instances running Postgresql - they are not RDS as that is only MySql as you say.

Usually you can tell they are Amazon instances from the DATABASE_URL config variable that Heroku sets.